# Amazon AWS EC2 .htaccess is not working

Tags: .htaccess, amazon-web-services, mod-rewrite, amazon-ec2

I updated .htaccess with the following code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
    ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
</IfModule>
```

and restarted the apache, it always redirects me to 404 instead of pages where as it is working in my local, as i gone through many posts under stackoverflow, my mod write is enabled and updated this too in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default

```
DocumentRoot /var/www
<Directory />
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
allow from all
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need change below files available in this path /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

Comment: But there is no such files available in my host. no httpd conf

Comment: After change in default  files. Have you restart apache server?

Comment: if it is not working then assign DocumentRoot /var/www/html after that restart apache server

Comment: Yes i did restart the apache server. Now where to assign this one ?
DocumentRoot /var/www/html

Comment: /etc/apache2/sites-available/default -> DocumentRoot /var/www replace with DocumentRoot /var/www/html

Comment: Still the 404 fires instead of original file.

Comment: Have you restart your server after above changes?

Comment: Yes i restarted the server as well!
sudo service apache2 restart
My file what it shows is 000-default.conf, i did all change to this file  under the provided path